# Refinery CMS - Styling the actual backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

Is there anyway to style the actual Refinery backend? Ideally I'd like to make it look a bit nicer and even add some javascript animation to some of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refinery's erb pages and stylesheets are stored in the gem, not the root of your application.

In OSX, these files can be found at

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-b4c324577513/core/app/views/refinery
```

and

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-b4c324577513/core/app/views/assets/stylesheets
```

respectively. The gem number ('b4c324577513') will be different for everyone who installs the gem, so change the paths accordingly.